Prove that $\prod\limits_{\mathrm{cyc}} a(a + 2)\leq \prod\limits_{\mathrm{cyc}} (1-a)^2$ for $a + b + c + d = 1$

Let $a,b,c,d\in (0;1); a+b+c+d=1$. Prove $$abcd(a+2)(b+2)(c+2)(d+2)\leq (1-a)^2(1-b)^2(1-c)^2(1-d)^2.$$

I have the following direction:
$\dfrac{(1-a)^2}{a(a+2)}.\dfrac{(1-b)^2}{b(b+2)}. \dfrac{(1-c)^2}{c(c+2)}. \dfrac{(1-d)^2}{d(d+2)} \leq 1$
$\Leftrightarrow \sum ln(\dfrac{(1-a)^2}{a(a+2)}) \leq 0$.
And use Jensen's inequality for concave functions. But $f(x)=\dfrac{(1-x)^2}{x(z+2)}$ is not concave on $ (0;1)$.
I think in another direction:
$(1+2/a)(1+2/b)(1+2/c)(1+2/d)\leq (1-1/a)^2(1-1/b)^2(1-1/c)^2(1-1/d)^2$
Let $x=1/a;y=1/b,z=1/c,t=1/d$ then $1/x+1/y+1/z+1/t=1$ and
$(1+2x)(1+2y)(1+2z)(1+2t)\leq (1-x)^2(1-y^2)(1-z)^2(1-t)^2$
$\Leftrightarrow \sum x^2 +\sum x^2y^2 \geq 2\sum xy(x+y)+4\sum x$
I have not been able to prove this inequality yet. Please help me.

The sum of logarithms $\le 0$ not $1.$

You can use Karamata's inequality.
WLOG we can assume that $a\geq b\geq c\geq d$. Taking natural log on both sides we have to prove
$$ \ln (ab+2a)+\ln (bc+2b)+\ln (cd+2c)+\ln (da+2d) \leq $$
$$ \leq \ln((1-d)(1-c))+\ln((1-c)(1-b))+\ln((1-d)(1-a)) +\ln((1-b)(1-a))$$
Set $x_1=ab+2a, \ \ldots, \ x_4=da+2d$ and $y_1=(1-d)(1-c), \ \ldots, \ y_4=(1-b)(1-a)$.
Assume $y_1\geq y_2\geq y_3\geq y_4$ (we don't know if $y_2\geq y_3$ or $y_2 \leq y_3$ but proof is similar in another case). We have to prove that $(x_i)$ majorizes $(y_i)$:
$$ x_1 = ab+2a\geq (1-d)(1-c)=1-c-d+cd=y_1$$
because $ab\geq cd$ and $2a+c+d\geq a+b+c+d=1$.
$$ x_1+x_2= ab+bc+2a+2b \geq (1-d)(1-c)+(1-c)(1-b)=y_1+y_2$$
because $ab+bc\geq cd+bc$ and $2a+2b+d+c+c+b\geq 2a+2b+2c+2d=2$.
$$ ab+bc+cd+2a+2b+2c\geq (1-d)(1-c)+(1-c)(1-b)+(1-d)(1-a)$$
because $ab+bc+cd\geq cd+bc+ad$ and $3a+3b+4c+2d\geq 3(a+b+c+d)=3$.
And finally
$$ \sum_{i=1}^4x_i=ab+bc+cd+da+2=\sum_{i=1}^4y_i.$$
We proved that $(x_i)$ majorizes $(y_i)$ and beacause natural log is a concave function then according to Karamata's inequality we get what we wanted.

yeah the $\sum_ix_i$ and $\sum_iy_i$ are decidedly not equal.

You're right. I hope now the proof is correct.

WLOG, assume that $d = \min(a, b, c, d)$. Let $q := ab + bc + ca$.
We have $q \le (a + b + c)^2/3 = (1 - d)^2/3$.
We have
$$abc \le \frac{(ab + bc + ca)^2}{3(a + b + c)} = \frac{q^2}{3(1-d)}, \tag{1}$$
and
\begin{align*}
 (a + 2)(b + 2)(c + 2)
 &\le \frac{[(a + 2)(b + 2) + (b+2)(c+2) + (c+2)(a+2)]^2}{3(a + 2 + b + 2 + c + 2)}\\
 &= \frac{(q + 16 - 4d)^2}{3(7 - d)}, \tag{2}
\end{align*}
and
\begin{align*}
 (1-a)(1-b)(1-c)
 &= 1 - (a + b + c) + (ab + bc + ca) - abc\\
 &\ge 1 - (a + b + c) + (ab + bc + ca) - \frac{(ab + bc + ca)^2}{3(a + b + c)} \\
 &= d + q - \frac{q^2}{3(1 - d)}  \tag{3}
\end{align*}
where we use (1).
Using (1)-(3), it suffices to prove that
$$\frac{q^2}{3(1 - d)} \cdot d \cdot \frac{(q + 16 - 4d)^2}{3(7 - d)} \cdot (d + 2)
\le \left[d + q - \frac{q^2}{3(1 - d)} \right]^2(1 - d)^2,$$
or
$$\sqrt{\frac{d(d + 2)}{9(1 - d)(7 - d)}} \cdot q(q + 16 - 4d)
\le \left[d + q - \frac{q^2}{3(1 - d)} \right](1 - d). \tag{4}$$
Let $f(q) := \mathrm{RHS}_{(4)} - \mathrm{LHS}_{(4)}$.
Clearly, $f(q)$ is concave.
Note that $0 \le q \le (1-d)^2/3$.
We have $f(0) = d(1-d) \ge 0$. It suffices to prove that $f((1-d)^2/3) \ge 0$, or
\begin{align*}
 &\sqrt{\frac{d(d + 2)}{9(1 - d)(7 - d)}} \cdot (1-d)^2/3 ((1-d)^2/3 + 16 - 4d)\\
 \le{}& \left[d + (1-d)^2/3 - \frac{((1-d)^2/3)^2}{3(1 - d)} \right](1 - d),
\end{align*}
or
\begin{align*}
 &\sqrt{\frac{d(d + 2)}{9(1 - d)(7 - d)}} \cdot \frac19(1-d)^2(7-d)^2\\
 \le{}& \frac{1}{27}(1-d)(d+2)^3
\end{align*}
which is true.
We are done.
